# Fortran Type Is (Character)

Tags: fortran

I am getting the following error when trying to use
`character` in `Type Is`

```
gfortran -o build/lib/larsa.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/larsa.f
lib/larsa.f:1558.14:

 Type Is (Character)
          1
Error: The type-spec at (1) shall specify that each length type parameter is assumed
lib/larsa.f:1490.14:

 Type Is (Character)
          1
Error: The type-spec at (1) shall specify that each length type parameter is assumed
```

This is the subroutine I have coded

```
Subroutine splits                    &
  (                                  &
    s, delim,                        &
    t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8,  & 
    pos                              &
  )

Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: s, delim
Character (len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos

Class (*), Intent (out) :: t1
Class (*), Intent (out), Optional :: t2, t3, t4,  &
          t5, t6, t7, t8

Integer :: nf

Select Type (t1)

 Type Is (Character(len=*))

   If (Present (pos)) Then

     If (Present (t5)) Then

       If (Present (t8)) Then    
         Call splits_str_to_str (s, delim, t1, t2, t3, t4,  &
              t5, t6, t7, t8, pos)
       Else If (Present (t7)) Then
         Call splits_str_to_str (s, delim, t1, t2, t3, t4,  &
              t5, t6, t7, pos)
       Else If (Present (t6)) Then
         Call splits_str_to_str (s, delim, t1, t2, t3, t4,  &
              t5, t6, pos)
```

Furthermore, I am using unlimited polymorphic entities on quite a few arguments. 
Things then get complicated to have `Select Type` for all of them. The compiler
is giving me the error

```
gfortran -o build/lib/larsa.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/larsa.f
lib/larsa.f:1569.51:

         Call splits_str_to_str (s, delim, t1, t2, t3, t4,  &
                                               1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 's2' at (1); passed CLASS(*) to CHARACTER(1)
lib/larsa.f:1572.51:

         Call splits_str_to_str (s, delim, t1, t2, t3, t4,  &
                                               1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 's2' at (1); passed CLASS(*) to CHARACTER(1)
lib/larsa.f:1575.51:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the syntax problem explained by IanH - you must use `character(*)` in select type - I will add something to your second problem. Possibly that should have been a new question.

You cannot assume that you know that two objects have the same dynamic type. You have to list all of them as selectors in `select type` otherwise the non-listed ones remain polymorphic. This is the very same reason why you use `select type` for `t1`.

I will also ads that it seems that your routine `splits_str_to_str` accepts optional arguments. In that case you don't have to test presents of all of them, you can pass them as optional actual arguments even if not present.

Unfortunately, to use them in `select type` as selectors you still need to test their presence.

One big design question remains. Why doesn't  have `splits` `character` dummy arguments? Why it needs unlimited polymorphics?

Comment: Yes, the arguments t2 to s8 are defined as optional in `splits_str_to_str`.

Comment: Because I would like `splits` to handle splitting not only to  characters, but also to numbers (integer, real, double precision, real(real128))

Comment: @Zeus That sounds like a task for ordinary generic from Fortran 90.

Comment: If I could do it with unlimited polymorphism, it will save me from having a multitude of separate subroutines. The only difference will be in the output bit. This is not the only operation I will have as most of the things I am doing have to handle the different types.

Comment: Can you show me how to list all of them as selectors in select type please?

Comment: It seems to me that `Select Type` only accepts a single variable.

Comment: @Zeus Yes only one. But you must use it for all of the polymorphic variables in your case. That means you have to nest the constructs.

Comment: 8 nested constructs. Polymorphic might not be a good thing in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a consequence of the syntax rules and constraints for SELECT TYPE.

Conceptually the type selection is limited to the dynamic type of the object and any kind parameters for that type.  The block to be executed is not chosen based on length type parameters, hence the syntax requires the specification of the length type parameter to be assumed.

So you simply want:

`TYPE IS (CHARACTER(*))`

Without the assumed specification, the implication of the syntax would be that the length type parameter of the selector had to match the default value of that parameter for the character type, i.e. 1.